# bc30526 property cell is 'read only' DataGridView1 to excel

Tags: vb.net

I am getting error from this line **xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()** the error is saying **bc30526 property cell is 'read only'** how can configure this one?

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
    For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
    Next
Next
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\vbexcel.xlsx")
xlWorkBook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: I think the problem is self-descriptive.  It looks like the problem is that you're trying to change the value of a cell by assigning to the cell, which the interop library won't let you do.  I think you need to assign to `Value`.

Comment: @Craig, how? please post your answer

Comment: Re the nullrefexception, I'd suggest asking a new question for that.  You're not doing things exactly the way I do, but it's not obvious that the difference is wrong.

Comment: @Craig , oh okay, i just hoping that you can help me with this new error, but thanks anyway. ill try my best to configure this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost certainly should be,

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
```

As written, you're trying to assign a string to a `Cell`; that wouldn't work even if it weren't read-only.

This might be a difference from VBA.  I think VBA allows the `Value` to be elided via default properties.  I don't think this is something that still exists in .NET, with the exception of indexers (the ability to omit `Item` accessing a collection).

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object variable or With block variable not set.'